# TimerTask & Timer running multiple times

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, timertask, autoscroll

I am trying to add auto scroll behavior to View Pager like carousel, which will auto rotate the images after 5 seconds. For this i am using Timer and TimerTask.
I have written that code in Main Activity.

Code snippets

**MainActivity**

```
SliderTimer sliderTimer;
Timer timer;

public void startAutoScroll() {

    totalItemsCarousel = caroouselimagesurl.size();

    if (null == timer) {
        timer = new Timer();
    } else {
        timer = null;
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    if (null == sliderTimer) {
        currentPage = GlobalApp.getInstance().getLastSelectedCarouselIndex();
        sliderTimer = new SliderTimer("812-" + threadCounter);
        threadCounter++;
    } else {
        sliderTimer = null;
        sliderTimer = new SliderTimer("818-" + threadCounter);
        threadCounter++;
    }

    sliderTimer.isStopped = false;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(sliderTimer, 5000, 5000);
}

int threadCounter = 0;
boolean isAutoScrollPaused = false;

public class SliderTimer extends TimerTask {
    String name;

    public SliderTimer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public volatile boolean isStopped = false;

    public boolean isStopped() {
        return isStopped;
    }

    public void setStopped(boolean stopped) {
        isStopped = stopped;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

         if (isStopped) {

            timer.cancel();
            sliderTimer.cancel();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;

        }

        if (!isAutoScrollPaused) {

            if (currentPage == (totalItemsCarousel - 1)) {
                currentPage = 0;
            } else {
                incrementCurrentPositon();
            }

            try {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public int incrementCurrentPositon() {
    int temp = currentPage;

    if (!isAutoScrollPaused) {
        currentPage = ++temp;
        temp = currentPage;
    } 

    return temp;
}

public void modifyCurrentPage(int newPos) {
   currentPage = newPos;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    isAutoScrollPaused = true;
    sliderTimer.setStopped(true);
    sliderTimer.cancel();

}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

        startAutoScroll();

}
```

Here when i navigate to any other activity and come back to MainActivity, multiple instances are updating the ViewPager hence resulting in auto scrolling the ViewPager before 5 seconds.
Hence my question is how would i stop the view pager being access by multiple threads.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Don't introduce multithreading into your project unless you absolutely need to. It is much better to do this with `postAtTime()` or a `CountDownTimer()`, which will run on the UI thread.

Comment: @greeble31 . Hi. thanks for the answer. can u provide any code or link which will lead me to the way.